# Unable to getParam()

Tags: php, magento

I wanted to add an action on Sales>Order in Magento admin.

Screenshot-
[image]

I followed the second method from this blog- [www.blog.magepsycho.com/adding-new-mass-action-to-admin-grid-in-magento/](http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/adding-new-mass-action-to-admin-grid-in-magento/)

My problem-
I am not able to get the order id (for performing the action on it) in the action controller.
My code in `class MyPackage_MyModule_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action`

```
protected function _initOrder()
{
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id'); ///TROUBLE HERE
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id);

    if (!$order->getId()) {
        $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('This order no longer exists.'));
        $this->_redirect('dash/sales_order');
        $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        return false;
    }
    Mage::register('sales_order', $order);
    Mage::register('current_order', $order);
    return $order;
}
public function approvecodAction() {
    if ($order = $this->_initOrder()) {
        try {
            $order->setStatus('codapproved')
                ->save();
            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                $this->__('The order has been approved for COD.')
            );
        }catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        }catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('The order has not been approved for COD.'));
            Mage::logException($e);
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $order->getId()));
    }
}
```

Note I copied the above two functions from `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php` and modified for my purpose.

**Please tell me how and where to set the parameter order id? Or if they are getting set, then how to get them?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dealing with a mass action callback on the controller, so you will be getting an array of values in the parameter instead of a single value. You're going to need to do something more like this in your action method:

```
public function approvecodAction() {
    $orderIds = $this->getRequest()->getPost('order_ids', array());
    foreach ($orderIds as $orderId) {
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);

        try {
            $order->setStatus('codapproved')
            ->save();
            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                    $this->__('The order has been approved for COD.')
            );
        }catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        }catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('The order has not been approved for COD.'));
            Mage::logException($e);
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $order->getId()));
}
```

Hope that helps!